# Should this question have gotten migrated here?

Tags: discussion

[how to migrate data from spreadsheet to SQL server management](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2591/how-to-migrate-data-from-spreadsheet-to-sql-server-management)

I don't know that this question really fits here. It seems like it is a tool issue (SO) and not so much a dba issue. That being said, had the user been registered and not anonymous, and had they given more information (such as perhaps that they had thousands of rows instead of maybe dozens of cells) then perhaps something could have been added to contribute.

I'm just curious what is the stance of the community of "does this particular question belong here" on account of it can be indicative of a whole class of questions.

Answer (score 4):

I would say that it belongs here, as DB tools knowledge is also required to properly administer a DB. Tools are being used in the background when certain DB tasks (eg: mirroring, log shipping, replication) are being executed. Tools are also used to performance monitoring, and error reporting. Hence, this extra information should also be in a DBA's utility belt.

Comment: But excel? Really that's my sticking point on this. Ah well, to see if the asker adopts it and comes here and makes a go of things

Comment: @drachenstern - I don't think excel is the issue, the question is about loading data from an external source into an RDBMS, it doesnt matter if it is excel, text, csv or whatever, especially as the first step of the answer could be "save the spreadsheet as csv"

Comment: @JackPDouglas ~ Good and valid points.

Answer (score 3):

I completely agree with @Stan

I feel, DBA tools and data migration questions are important here. Actually I flagged this question in SO to migrate here...

Lets hope it will fit here :)

Comment: Given your comments on it, I rather figured you had.

Answer (score 1):

If the class of questions is [ETL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load) then I'd say they all belong here